# Simple Droid App force closes when switching activities

Tags: java, android

I new to app development and I have been working on a Flash card app. There is a main screen and the user chooses a button. On the emulator when I touch a button to go to a new activity, my app force closes. 
I have added the activity in the manifest.
The second activity has its own layout (main2.xml).
My buttons look like this:

```
Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent addIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Add.class);
        startActivity(addIntent);

    }
});
```

Any ideas of what's going wrong? If more info is needed I can supply it, I've been stuck here for two days. 
Thanks

Comment: You need to send the logcat output.

Comment: Are there any errors in your log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity in the manifest should look like this:

```
<activity android:name="ActivityClassName" 
          android:label="label"
    <intent-filter>
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action
            android:name="my.package.ACTIVITY_NAME" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You then can start it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.package.ACTIVITY_NAME");            
startActivity(intent);
```

To get more help post the manifest file and the exception you get, when the application crashes. You can see that in Eclipse's debug perspective, in the LogCat view.

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.apps.math/.Subtract } from ProcessRecord{43fb72f8 279:com.apps.math/10032} (pid=279, uid=10032) requires android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES
                 
  This is what I get in LogCat, after the "Fatal Error" message. I can post the manifest if it will help.

Answer (score 0):

you can not call startActivity on OnClickListener. you need to call it on your application context object or activity object.

```
Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
Context ctx=this;
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent addIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Add.class);
        ctx.startActivity(addIntent);
    }
});
```